# Wordpress - show all posts + ones with specific tag

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, filter, tags

I have 3 types of posts as below

1. Normal posts without any tag
2. With "featured" tag
3. With "sold" tag

On a page, I just want to show normal posts + ones with featured tag and don't want to show posts with "sold" tag. How can I do the query for this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_posts` function with the `tax_query` parameter.

Because it's pretty simple I don't think I should write anything further, just read
the next part from the codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

You should preferably use the `WP_Query`, doing something like this:

```
// you'll need the term_id of the tags you would like to exclude
$sold_tag = get_term_by('name','sold','post_tag');
$featured_tag = get_term_by('name','featured','post_tag');


// create a query object, this will pick all posts except the ones tagged with 'sold'
// if you wanted to pick all post marked as sold or featured and everyone not marked
// as for instance 'fruit' + all that isn't tagged at all you could use a combination of
// tag__not_in => array($fruit->term_id) && tag => array('featured,sold')
//
$query = new WP_Query( 
   array('post_type' => 'post', 
         'tag__not_in' => array(
            $sold_tag->term_id
         )
  ) 
);
// start the loop
while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
    // output post here ...
endwhile;
```

Read more about [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)